# MultipleLines text Box

Tags: html, asp.net

I need to implement functionality shown in diagram(text area with formatting capability). Can someone just point me in the correct direction?

Note-As Soon as I click on Text Area,this formatting tool comes automatically above.

[image: Text Area with Formatting option]

I am trying something like below code:

```
  <asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" /></div>
```

OR

```
  <textarea id="TextArea2" runat="server" name="S1" Columns="50"></textarea></p>
```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: the above object is generally referred to as a rich text box, it is not a built in asp.net control as far as i know.  Here is one (i haven't tried it out) that seems to be built for asp.net http://www.freetextbox.com/

Comment: I tried with textarea also,but that top foramtting tool is not visible.

Comment: because the text area does not contain such formatting tools.  text area and text box != rich text box

Comment: Thanks,I will try with FreeTextBox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two WYSIWYG rich text editors that have stood the test of time are [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/).

For most of the projects, ***the difference between the two that you should care about is which editor offers the feature set and appearance that are most similar to what you have in mind***.

The discussion for which one is better than the other won't be very fruitful because both are very good in their own ways.